# How to test ZeroMQ in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, zeromq

I have tried to test activemq in jmeter, but I want to test zeromq performance. The zeromq server is working. How should I operate in jmeter?

Comment: Welcome to SO please see the article before post your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: you have to be more specific.

Comment: @Kiril S. Thank you for the reply. I want to know how to configure JMeter so as to test samples of ZeroMQ. For example, which type of sampler is used and how to modify the configuration file?